# Converting NSSet to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

Currently I have a subclass of NSManaged object called Folder with property called item that is of type NSSet.

```
class Folder: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var item: NSSet

func itemMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {

    var mutableArray: NSMutableArray!

    mutableArray = [item.allObjects]

    return mutableArray

}
```

Item class:

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var completed: Bool
```

Does anybody have any suggestions with where I am currently going wrong ?

Here is my previous function I was using which now I want to convert my NSSet to an NSMutableArray.

```
func itemArray() -> [Item] {
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)
    return item.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([sortDescriptor]) as! [Item]
}
```

Comment: .copy always remember to get the copy() of stuff. After that, if still error, it's not related to array.

Comment: Sorry I am new to iOS development and unsure what you mean by the using copy method.

Comment: .allKeys doesn't create an array (unless Swift does it, which normally happens when you change stuff), you get a Pointer instead. Variables, in most languages, just point to memory. In other words, you don't have your own .allKeys until you get a clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func itemMutableArray() -> NSMutableArray {
    return NSMutableArray(array: (item.allObjects as! [Item]).sorted{ $0.date.compare($1.date) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending } )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @JKSDEV The question is how to convert from NSSet to NSMutableArray. I think the question is answered

Comment: Oh you've changed your answer, unsure exactly what's going on tbh. I did include the Item class in my question. Will try out your suggestion now.

Comment: Get the error "Expressions are not allowed at the top level" when using outside my class statement and error "Expected Declaration" when within the parentheses.

Comment: The question was kind of in two parts I guess. You answered how to convert to NSMutableArray and helped me creating a new function so will give you the answer for that. Will post a new question for the error in table view. I really appreciate the time you put in (Y)

Answer (score 0):

use Swift types, they are much more versatile

This puts the NSSet into an Array (`var` is mutable) and sorts it ascending by property `date`

```
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var item: NSSet

var sortedItemArray : Array<Item> {
  var array = item.allObjects as! [Item]
  return sorted(array) {$0.date < $1.date }
}
```

Comment: I like your suggestion but unfortunately get the following error 'Cannot find overload for 'sorted' that accepts the argument list of type '[(Item], (_, _) -> _)'

Comment: what type is `Item` ?

Comment: Item is of type NSSet, a subclass of NSManagedObjected with three attributes of type string, bool and date. Folder has a one to many relation with Item.